# Como consultar registros entre dos tablas relacionadas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, poo

quiero hacer la consulta de un tabla seccion y de ella mostrar los datos de otra tabla que esta relacionada, llamada semestres. Necesito ayuda de como consultarla en el controlador y como mostrar los datos en la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador

```
public function registros()
    {
         $seccion=Seccion::paginate (5);
return view ('/registros-secciones',compact('seccion') );


    }
```

en mi vista

{{$seccion[nombreseccion]}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es una consulta con [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) de la siguiente manera:

```
$records = DB::table('semestre')
             ->join('seccion', 'seccion.semestre_id', '=', 'semestre.id')
             ->paginate(5);
```

Esto te traera todos los registros de semestre y podrás acceder a la propiedad `nombresección`

Otra forma de hacerlo es a travez de las [relaciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships), en tu modelo de semestre puedes crear la siguiente relación:

**Si es 1 a muchos es:**

```
function secciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ruta de tu modelo de section', 'semestre_id');
}
```

**Si es relación 1 a 1:**

```
function seccion()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Ruta de tu modelo de sección', 'semestre_id');
}
```

Con esa función anterior lo que haces es que consultas un registro de semestre y puedes acceder directamente a su relación de la siguiente forma, tomando como ejemplo la relación 1 a 1:

```
$semestre = Semestre::find('ID del semestre');
$nombre_seccion = $semestre->seccion->nombreseccion;
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda